# How to capture all the output from a subprocess that *writes to stdin*?

Tags: python, subprocess, ipc, stdin

I want to use Python's `subprocess.Popen` to execute a child process, and collect all its output.

The problem is that the process in question writes not only to `stdout` and `stderr`, but *sometimes also to* `stdin` <sup>1</sup>.

I want to capture all three of these output streams *separately*.

Naively, I tried this:

```py
import subprocess

...

proc = subprocess.Popen(('/usr/bin/modulecmd', 'python', 'help', 'null'),
                        shell=False,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,)

stdout = proc.stdout.read()
stderr = proc.stderr.read()
stdin = proc.stdin.read()

proc.wait()
```

...but when the expression `proc.stdin.read()` is evaluated, an exception ensues (`io.UnsupportedOperation: read`).

Does anyone know how to use `subprocess.Popen` to handle this situation?

(BTW, I did try to implement a subclass of `subprocess.Popen` to support this use-case, but I kept running into errors similar to the one mentioned above.  I just don't understands `subprocess.Popen`'s internals well enough.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/667660/10618, as well as the comments therein, for a good discussion of this unusual behavior.</sup>

Comment: Can you replace `stdin` in `Popen` with an actual file, maybe from `tempfile.TemporaryFile` and then read from that file?

Comment: Don't use programs that write to stdin, that's just completely broken.

Comment: Stdin (FD 0) is normally connected to a tty and a tty is read-write. When redirected/captured, FD is replaced by a pipe and a pipe is always unidirectional, i.e. either read or write. IMHO not only you cannot capture it, but the program is unable to write to stdin when executed with redirected stdin. Maybe a pseudo-terminal can help, but I'm not sure, I don't know them into such details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the redirection function of the shell, like this.

```
import shlex
...
args = ('/usr/bin/modulecmd', 'python', 'help', 'null')
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.join(args) + ' 0>&1',
    shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
...
```

If you don't want to depend on an external program such as a shell, you have to implement on your own using os.fork(), os.exec(), os.pipe(), etc. See [subprocess.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.8/Lib/subprocess.py).